# Как увеличить размер точек, которые маскируют пароль в EditText?

Tags: android

Указываю `EditText`

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Как увеличить размер точек, за которыми прячется пароль в `EitText`, не изменяя размер текста?

Comment: насчет увеличить не уверен, но символ точки(.) можно например заменить на звездочку(*)

Comment: @ermak0ff на счет замены я видел возможность, но нужно увеличить

Comment: ну так замените на увеличенную точку - (•)))

Comment: @ermak0ff интересное предложение, попробую

Comment: @ermak0ff Пробую подобрать точку по дизайну, либо сильно маленькая либо большая. Буду другое решение искать.

Comment: ну если из всех доступных символов, не нашли тот единственный, который будет подходить по дизайну, то наверно надо создавать свою вью и рисовать на канве.(или может в опенсорсе есть что подходящее)

Comment: @ermak0ff думаю не так просто будет это сделать. С учетом того, что нужно сохранить поведение, которое по умолчанию происходит (курсор, ввод текста в нужном месте, смена последнего символа на точку)

Answer (score 6):

У `EditText` есть метод `setTransformationMethod()`

В который передаем экземпляр данного класса:

```
private class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source;
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '●'; 
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); 
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно самое интересное тут в методе `charAt`:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
   return '●'; 
}
```

Который и возвращает символ, который будет отображать введенный символ пароля.

Итого с данным PasswordTransformationMethod:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дефолтное поведение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, для меня этот символ слишком крупный получается. Пробовал '•', '●', '.', и ещё какой то.